# Call external function inside jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-slider

I am writing a simple Range Slider Plugin with Left and Right Button.

I am using jQuery ui slider for this.

So on slide or on click i want to call a external function inside the plugin.

**Plugin Code :**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.rangeSliders = function(customText){
        var selector = this.selector + ' #slider';
        $(this).html('<div id="sliderContainer"><div id="arrowL" class="left"><img src="left.png" alt="prev" width="28" height="28" id="imgPrev" /></div><div id="slider" ></div><div id="arrowR" class="left" ><img src="right.png" alt="prev" width="28" height="28"  id="imgPrev"/></div></div>');
        $( selector ).slider({
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 9,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
               calculate(ui.value);
            }
        });

        $("#arrowL").click(function () {
            s.slider('value', s.slider('value') - s.slider("option", "step"));
            //calculate(s.slider('value'));
            });
        $("#arrowR").click(function () {
            s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider("option", "step"));
            calculate(s.slider('value'));
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

**Using the Plugin inside my html**

```
<div id="slider1"> </div>

function calculate(){
 //I will get the value from the slider and do some actions
}

$('$slider1').rangeSliders();
```

I am getting error saying calculate is not defined.

Can you any one suggest me a nice way to get this value or call external function inside the plugin.

Comment: why not moving the `calculate()` function into your plugin as a private function?

Comment: @VDesign I want to use this plugin for many pages, Ever time the logic will change according to the page they use.

Comment: How many different `calculate()` logic functions will you have?

Comment: i am using rangeSlider plugin for atleast 17 pages now.Each page has it own logic and functionality.

Comment: is there any way to do that approach in different way: For Example on slide i want to get the value from my html page.

Comment: add what if you provide your `calculate()` function with a `param` to define which logic to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a new parameter to the plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.rangeSliders = function(customText, myCalc){
        var selector = this.selector + ' #slider';
        $(this).html('<div id="sliderContainer"><div id="arrowL" class="left"><img src="left.png" alt="prev" width="28" height="28" id="imgPrev" /></div><div id="slider" ></div><div id="arrowR" class="left" ><img src="right.png" alt="prev" width="28" height="28"  id="imgPrev"/></div></div>');
        $( selector ).slider({
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 9,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
               if($.isFunction(myCalc))
                   myCalc(s.slider('value'));
            }
        });

        $("#arrowL").click(function () {
            s.slider('value', s.slider('value') - s.slider("option", "step"));
            if($.isFunction(myCalc))
                myCalc(s.slider('value'));
            });
        $("#arrowR").click(function () {
            s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider("option", "step"));
            if($.isFunction(myCalc))
                myCalc(s.slider('value'));
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

now you can change your page like this:

```
<div id="slider1"> </div>

function calculate(){
 //I will get the value from the slider and do some actions
}

$('$slider1').rangeSliders(undefined, calculate);
```

note that I pass undefined as the first parameter for `customText` so it is still being handled as if you called it as `$('$slider1').rangeSliders();`, but still leaves you the chance to put in a custom text. The calculate function is being passed as the second parameter. Be aware to pass it with the NAME ONLY, do not add the () at the end.